# Filling the empty bottle with hot air

Tags: vacuum, air, solar-system, weather

1. If I were to fill the empty empty bottle with hot air, how can it be done? If I leave the bottle out in the sunny weather, will the bottle fill with hot air?
2. When I am filling the empty bottle with hot air, does that mean I am filling it with helium?
3. Does a vacuum cleaner really fills the substance (balloon, bottle, etc.) with vacuum?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I were to fill the empty empty bottle with hot air, how can it be done?

Blow hot air in to the bottle. I would blow it in through a long skinny tube (e.g., like a straw) that reaches all the way to the bottom so that the hot air can push whatever was already there (e.g., cool air) out through the bottle neck.

> If I leave the bottle out in the sunny weather, will the bottle fill with hot air?

That might depend on what you mean by "hot." If the bottle absorbs a substantial fraction of sunlight (e.g., if it's painted black) then the bottle could become almost-but-maybe-not-quite too hot to touch with bare hands, and the heat of the bottle would be conducted to the air that is contained within.

> When I am filling the empty bottle with hot air, does that mean I am filling it with helium?

Helium is not air. Air is not helium.

> Does a vacuum cleaner really fills the substance (balloon, bottle, etc.) with vacuum?

Pretending that vacuum is a substance with which a space can be filled probably will not help you to understand or solve any problems. A vacuum cleaner can lower the pressure of air within a rigid container, but probably not lower it by much. A more powerful vacuum *pump* can remove most of the air from a container. We sometimes say that the container "contains vacuum" in that case, but that's technically inaccurate. The container actually contains *nothing,* not even air.

Practically nobody ever talks about filling a space with vacuum. Better instead to talk about *evacuating* the space.

Comment: I guess after the bottle is filled with hot air, would I close it up with a lid?

Answer (score 0):

You may do what people do for hot-air balloons: turn the bottle upside down and hold something like a butane lighter under the (opening of the) bottle. The hot air will accumulate at the top and displace colder air.